# Is it legally fine to name a project or a library with a famous person name?

Tags: software

I wonder if there are any legal reasons for that to be not ok?

There are many precedents, e.g. `Sinatra`, `Kafka`, `Shakespeare`, `Django` etc , so are there any limitations ? (living people etc)

Comment: You're effectively using a person's name to promote a product, so no, you cannot claim a link to that person without their permission. There may be an exception where a product is named after a widely used term or phrase. For example: if I create a wonderful machine and name it a Hawking Radiation Detector then I doubt Stephen Hawking would be too upset about this (Hawking radiation being the widely adopted term here). If I name it the Stephen Hawking Detector, however, I'm clearly claiming a link to the man himself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have as much money as Apple, and the famous person is Carl Sagan, then you change the name of your internal project instead of risking a law suit. The difference is probably that Sagan is alive and can sue you, while that is no problem with Kafka, Django etc.

Dead or alive is not the real distinction; don't try to to call your project "Disney". The question is whether there is someone who is going to sue you for it.

Comment: The estate of Frank Sinatra is quite alive and kicking and has even [won trademark issues recently](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/thr-esq/frank-sinatra-beats-hot-dog-franks-anatra-370206).

Comment: so I guess that using a first name can't be an issue then ? (e.g. franz, richard)

Comment: Carl Sagan has been dead for twenty years.